# wxPyhton selecting more rows in wxGrid by holding Shift

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to allow the user to select more rows in a Grid by holding the Shift-Button while clicking on the first and on the last row the user want to select.
I have tested this:

```
    def OnRangeSelect(self, event):
    if event.Selecting():
        top = event.GetTopRow()
        bottom = event.GetBottomRow()
        while top <= bottom:
            print bottom
            self.myGrid.SelectRow(top, True)
            top += 1
    event.Skip()
```

and this:

```
def OnRangeSelect(self, event):
    event.Skip()
```

but always the same happen...

but there are tricky things happen:
1) The function is calling -> all right
2) It doesn't select the rows although it goes into the loop(testet with the PyDev debugger)
3) If I select e.G. row 3 as top row and row 6 as bottom row, wxPython select all rows from 0 upto 6...

I don't know what to do...
Python-Version: 2.7
wxPython-Version 2.9

Answer (score 1):

Refer this code it might help:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib


class MyGrid(gridlib.Grid):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent)
        self.CreateGrid(12, 8)




        self.Bind(gridlib.EVT_GRID_RANGE_SELECT, self.OnshiftSelect)




    def OnshiftSelect(self, evt):
        if evt.Selecting():
            msg = 'Selected'
        else:
            msg = 'Deselected'
        print "OnshiftSelect: %s  top-left %s, bottom-right %s\n" % (msg, evt.GetTopLeftCoords(),
                                                                     evt.GetBottomRightCoords())
        evt.Skip()




class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Grid events")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        myGrid = MyGrid(panel)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(myGrid, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You are funny... if I tested this code want to output all the rows with holding shift, it also doesn't work... This is only the code example from wxDemo

Comment: This code works for me on Xubuntu, wxPython 2.8.12, Python 2.7

Comment: @alabamajack------- I think you are not clear about your requirement. Please come up with your requirement

Comment: It does NOT select any cells if I take a row(say 1) and then hold Shift while I take another row(say 6). If I let print the selectedrows with self.myGrid.GetSelectedRows() it returns only an empty list...